# Connect to a account and cluster using kube client java api

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I looking for a way to connect to a given aws account and cluster using kube client java api. the account and cluster details will be dynamic not constant

I have checked kube client java api, but did not getting option to make a connection from one pod to another aws account and cluster kube client

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems are you running into?  The Kubernetes API doesn't really know anything about AWS, and it can be used on several cloud providers, bare metal, and local systems.